# null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint Django form

Tags: python, django, forms

Trying to implement a file upload for a user profile page. I am recieving the following error:

> null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint
>   DETAIL:  Failing row contains (35,
>   profile/{now:%Y/%m/YmdHMSext_xg2iZ6M, null, null).

I've read that it probably has something to do with the User_ID, I tried passing form.user = request.user, but that didn't work. There are also two nulls, not just one.

**Models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    # First Name and Last Name do not cover name patterns
    # around the globe.
    name = models.CharField(_('Name of User'), blank=True, 
    max_length=255)
    #accepted_terms_of_service = models.Booleanfield()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('users:detail', kwargs={'username': 
self.username})

# Profile Image
def upload_to(instance, filename):
    now = timezone_now()
    base, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    ext = ext.lower()
    return "profile/{now:%Y/%m/%Y%m%d%H%M%S}{ext}"

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
on_delete='CASCADE', related_name='user_profile')
    school = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(_("Picture"), upload_to=upload_to, 
null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def add_image(request):
     form = ProfileImageForm()
     #form.user = request.user
     if request.method == "POST":
         form = ProfileImageForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
     if form.is_valid():
         form.save()
         return redirect('userPage')
     else:
         return render(request, "users/user_image_form.html", {"form": form
        })
```

**forms.py**

```
class ProfileImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ["image"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because in your `Profile` model you add `user` column as ForeignKey which enforce to `NOT NULL` so the error throw.
To solve this you need to modify `add_image` method something like this

```
@login_required
def add_image(request):
     form = ProfileImageForm()
     #form.user = request.user
     if request.method == "POST":
         form = ProfileImageForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
     if form.is_valid():
         form = form.save(commit=False) # change is here
         form.user=request.user.pk # change is here
         form.save()
         return redirect('userPage')
     else:
         return render(request, "users/user_image_form.html", {"form": form
```

The `request.user.pk` value get if you are logged in. But if you are logged in you need to assisn `form.user = your_specified_id` which id exists in `User` table.
If your case is, you are admin and you need to add an image to other users, so that you need to pass the user id in your `add_image` method.

Add in `ProfileImageForm.py`
add `user` in field list

Comment: So because I am modifying the model fields and user is not nullable, even though I'm not editting it, I need to specifiy it?

Comment: No you need to keep user in Profile model because you to reference which user image is. You need to modify your add_image method

Comment: It wants a user_instance, so I changed request.user.pk to request.user, but now it says there is a duplicate user_id.. 

The above exception (duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_profile_user_id_key" DETAIL: Key (user_id)=(13) already exists. ) was the direct cause of the following exception. Is this because there is already a profile created and its trying to save over it?

Comment: So, you need to update the user instance with an image. Not create a new one as relation is `OneToOne`

Comment: don't rebind the result of the `form.save()` call to the name "form" - it only makes the code confusing, what `form.save()` returns here is a Profile instance. Also, `profile.user` should be bound to `request.user` (a `User` instance), not to `request.user.pk` (an integer).

Answer (score 1):

I think its not necessary to have both Profile Model and [Custom User Model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser). Because, as you are customizing the User model already, why not put `Profile` model's fields to User model as well. You can approach like this:

```
# model

def upload_to(instance, filename):
    now = timezone_now()
    base, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    ext = ext.lower()
    return "profile/{now:%Y/%m/%Y%m%d%H%M%S}{ext}"


class User(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name of User'), blank=True, 
    max_length=255)
    school = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(_("Picture"), upload_to=upload_to, 
                              null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('users:detail', kwargs={'username': 
self.username})

# views

@login_required
def add_image(request):
     form = ProfileImageForm(data=request.POST or None, file=request.FILES or None, instance=request.user)
     if request.method == "POST":

        if form.is_valid():
             form.save()
             return redirect('userPage')

     return render(request, "users/user_image_form.html", {"form": form
        })

# forms.py

class ProfileImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["image"]
```

### Update

You can create a [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/signals/#post-save) signal, which will create a Profile Instance after each User is created.

```
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):

    if created:
        profile = Profile(user=instance)
        profile.save()

post_save.connect(create_user_profile,
                  sender=User,
                  dispatch_uid="profilecreation-signal")
```

Now in your form, you can directly pass this `Profile` instance:

```
@login_required
def add_image(request):
     form = ProfileImageForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)

     if request.method == "POST":
         if form.is_valid():
             form.save()
             return redirect('userPage')
     else:
         return render(request, "users/user_image_form.html", {"form": form
        })
```

For existing user, you can create Profile from shell:

```
for user in User.objects.all():
    Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
```

Comment: While I agree that having both a custom user and a profile model is _technically_ not necessary, the OP might have reasons (even if only historical) to have this design (or at least to keep it - migrating a huge production database can take litterally hours).

Comment: I have a subscription app that relies on the profile. I technically agree with what you are saying, but I'm a little too deep now.

Comment: Already have this! Thank you though!
def profileCallback(sender, request, user, **kwargs):
    userProfile, is_created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    if is_created:
        userProfile.name = user.username
        userProfile.save()